# Internal storage - free and occuppied space do not add to total

Tags: internal-storage, file-system

On Sony Xperia Z2, I have 5.6 GB on `/storage/emulated/0`, then 2.3 GB in `/`. However, the whole internal storage has 12 GB, and I can only see under 2 GB of free space.

Where is the remaining 2 GB?

Comment: Give us the output (screenshots only) of [Diskinfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo). Third point of this question may help you too: [Understand the storage of my phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/119681)